# MultiPlatform - Posting to friend timeline and sending invitation on facebook

Tags: php, android, ios, facebook, facebook-graph-api

Right now I'm trying to create a multiplatform application that connected to facebook.

I've successfully send invitation and posting to timeline via web application, right now I'm planning to post to timeline and sending invitation on facebook via android and iOS apps, I've already managed to authenticate and getting user data from the mobile device (android and iOS). So the question is can I send the token I get from the mobile device to the backend server via API and let the backend server post to timeline send invitation in the same way I post to timeline and send invitation? if yes how can I do it? is it possible if I use the graph API?

Answer (score 2):

Searched for the same about 2 weeks ago for my iOS app. From february 6 Facebook changed their policy: https://developers.facebook.com/roadmap/change-policy/

Now you can't post to friends or public page walls. I tried to solve this but unsuccessfully

Comment: ah too bad :( thanks for the information I'll vote your answer up for the information! I hope someone will come up with a solution for us :)